# Mediaplayer in c# windows application

Tags: c#, com, media-player

I have added and mediaplayer control to my c# application, and I can make it play a .wma song. My problem is that i want to see if the player is playing. Is there an event that I can use? Or is it a way I can see for how many seconds a song has been playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check the [PlayState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930667.aspx) property or handle the [PlayStateChange event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms909950.aspx).

Comment: The PlayState property appears to have been deprecated.